# Verify dnsmasq configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns, dnsmasq

How to verify `dnsmasq`'s configuration?

`dnsmasq` used to be able to give verbose info about itself in `/var/log/daemon.log`, as explained in [dnsmasq testing](http://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/providing-dhcp-and-dns-services-with-dnsmasq/#Test_Log).

However, when I restarted my dnsmasq service, nothing is logged to `/var/log/daemon.log`:

```
% echo "    *** DEBUG `date --rfc-3339=seconds` DEBUG *** " >> /var/log/daemon.log

% service dnsmasq restart 
* Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server dnsmasq                      [ OK ] 

% tail /var/log/daemon.log
*** DEBUG 2013-11-27 23:04:08-05:00 DEBUG ***
```

This is Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### --no-daemon

`dnsmasq` will print errors to the terminal if you run it directly. i.e. `dnsmasq --no-daemon`, or with all logging options:

```
$ dnsmasq --no-daemon --log-queries=extra --log-dhcp --log-debug -C /path/to/dnsmasq.conf
```

`dnsmasq` on its own will try to start dnsmasq, and gives a line number in the config if it finds any problems there.

#### --test

`dnsmasq --test` will do basic syntax checks on the config files. If successful, it should print something like

```
$ dnsmasq --test
dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
```

A contrived failure looks like

```
$ echo 'A-VERY-BAD-OPTION' > /tmp/tmp.conf
$ dnsmasq -C /tmp/tmp.conf --test

dnsmasq: bad option at line 1 of /tmp/tmp.conf
```

#### permissions

If you test without `sudo` then for a good config, dnsmasq should eventually reach the stage where it tries to start listening on port 53, but fails due to permissions.

If you use `sudo` (or you set `port=1024` or higher in the config) then dnsmasq should actually start running, but then you may have to `kill` the process manually.  If you've run with `--no-daemon`, this is easy to do with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>.

Comment: See also the manpage, hosted by the author at https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html .

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK dnsmasq will normally log to the syslog service. By default it uses facility DAEMON.

FWIW: "It works for me" (in Fedora 18 / 19).

If you aren't seeing any messages I'd suggest verifying your syslog configuration. Or, a more emperical approach, try something like "grep -c dnsmasq /var/log/*".

See also the detailed description of logging in the manual page here:
http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html

There are some other possibilities for logging mentioned there that can effect its behaviour e.g. if facility contains a '/' character.

Are other subsystems (sys-)logging correctly? Can you cause syslog to log a message by using the 'logger' command?

HTH!

Robb.

Comment: thanks. It worked for me as well, that was Debian. Thanks for the grep tip, now I found that in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy `dnsmasq` logs to `syslog` instead of `daemon.log`, even though the man page still says send syslog entries defaults to DAEMON.

Answer (score 2):

DNSMASQ is one of the common DNS/DHCP cace solution on linux/unix, some good links:

help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq
manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/dnsmasq.8.html
wiki.debian.org/HowTo/dnsmasq

1. Verification steps:
   Turn on the debug logging under /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

log-queries
log-dhcp

2. Then, restart and watch for logs when you dig hostname:

On debian variants, it dnsmasq logs by default in /var/log/syslog.